# Can I get upserted record Id in Azure Data Factory from Dynamics 365 Sales?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, dynamics-365

I have a pipeline in Azure Data Factory.
I have two datasets. I try to upsert to Dynamics 365 Contact entity from Azure SQL Database.
Here is my pipeline screenshot.

[image]

After upsert, I need to update my source dataset with the upserted record id on dynamics.

I couldn't find any documents online. I wonder is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're copying the data from Azure SQL database to Dynamic 365. When the source data modified, you want to make the sink data also be chanaged.

Just for now, there isn't a trigger for SQL database. You need use other service like [Logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview). It has the SQL Server trigger [when an item is modified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/):

- Microsoft SQL Server is a relational database management system
  developed by Microsoft. Connect to SQL Server to manage data. You can
  perform various actions such as create, update, get, and delete on
  rows in a table.
  [image]

Then use the [get a pipeline run active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatafactory/#get-a-pipeline-run) to call the Data Factory pipeline:

- Get a particular pipeline run execution
  [image]